# How to link my custom domain to a bluemix container

Tags: docker, containers, ibm-cloud

I have deployed a container on Bluemix adding my own docker image. It works well with the IP that is automatically linked, but I need to make it work with my custom domain (with HTTPS) that is already on "Manage organisations" and I can use perfectly on Cloud Foundry apps ("add route"). How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a Container Group and then you can add your custom domain in the same way you did for your Cloud Foundry app.

The container group default route will be similar to a Cloud Foundry default app, like mycontainer.mybluemix.net (if you are deploying in US South for example). Then you can add your custom route.

To create a container group via UI select the "Scalable" tab and follow instructions. You can use the same image you are using on your standalone container.

If you are using the cli you can use the `cf ic group` command group to create and manage your container groups.

Also you can expose only 1 port with container groups, so if your container exposes more than one port this will not work for you as well.

See documentation for Container Groups here:

https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_index.html

UPDATE: from @NFritze comment below you can allocate a public ip to a container group, but only at group create time, using the --ip parameter. IP cannot be shared (unlike route).

Comment: As a minor comment on this - you CAN allocate a public ip to a container group, but only at group create time, using the --ip parameter.  IP cannot be shared (unlike route).

Comment: thanks @NFritze - I will update the answer. I didn't know about this.